# What is the wxWidgets equivalent of a C# User Control

Tags: wxwidgets

I am currently designing the migration of my existing .NET / C# / WinForms project to a platform neutral solution and the most attractive alternative I have seen seems to be wxWidgets especially taking in consideration my familiarity with C++ and with MFC that appears to have a lot in common with it.

After going though the documentation and the sample code I need to clarify the following issue:

Is it a valid assumption that the way to develop a User Control (by C# terminology) in a wx environment is to derive a class from wxPanel , customize it and place it in a wxFrame?
 If this is the case what is the wxFrame method to be used to add the wxPanel object to it ?

The only relative method I was able to find was wxWindow::AddChild but the documentation states that is mostly internal to wxWidgets and shouldn't be called by the user code.

To avoid confusion please note that my question is about a User Control and not a Custom Control (which is clearly addressed in the documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to set the parent window in the constructor of your `wxPanel`-derived class and pass it to the inherited constructor (cf. [wxPanel constructor](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxpanel.html#wxpanelctor))

A better solution, though, is to use sizers (see [wx Sizers](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_sizeroverview.html#sizeroverview)) for layouting.

And yes, imo you're right about `wxPanel`being (roughly) the equivalent of a C# `UserControl`.

Comment: I am a little confused about the wxSizer::Add.

I can see that is signature looks like this:

wxSizerItem* Add(wxWindow* window, const wxSizerFlags& flags)

So to add a window to the sizer, it has to be created first.

But, wxPanel’s constructor looks like this:

wxPanel(wxWindow* parent, …..)

which means that the parent window has to be provided…

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have always to give the parent window in the constructor. The sizer mechanism works in parallel: you add all child controls to the sizer (using `sizer->Add`) and set the parent's  sizer property afterwards (using `parent->SetSizer`). Take a look at the (second) link, there's a short example.

Comment: Got it...  I will go ahead and download the framework and give it a try!